# List all routes from an application using Zend Framework 2

Tags: routes, zend-framework2

**How to easily list all routes that we have defined in our application with Zend Framework** 2?

By "routes" I mean those which are defined in:

`module/[moduleName]/config/module.config.php`

under

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        ...
    )
)
```

I need to list them all but I can't figure out how to do this easily and nor the documentation nor the forums helped me by now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can find the complete (merged) config or dump the Router itself. There is no way to export all route objects, so there I've to disappoint you.

To get the complete config, get it from the service locator:

```
// $sl instanceof Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager

$config = $sl->get('COnfig');
$routes = $config['router']['routes'];
```

If you want to view all routes just for debugging purposes, you can use `var_dump` or similar on the router object:

```
// $sl instanceof Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager

$router = $sl->get('Router');
var_dump($router);
```

To get route instances you can build the routes yourself using the route plugin manager, but I am not sure that's the way you want to go...

Comment: It helped me a lot. The first section of your answer did the trick ;) I needed this because I get a route on the first level which is variable and based on objects created by users. (for instance mywebsite.com/user-object-name, I had to validate that user-object-name isn't already used by one of my routes through a validator).

Thanks!

Comment: Note: additional (console) routes may be found under $config['console']['router']['routes'];

Comment: Router is a instance of TreeRouteStack. You can get all Routes by `$router->getRoutes())`.

Comment: It will result in a hierarchical print.

Answer (score 3):

To get all routes I use [ZFTool](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zendtool.introduction.html)

And console command to get dump of routes:

```
php vendor/bin/zf.php config list | grep routes
```

For Windows users (not tested):

```
php vendor/bin/zf.php config list |  findstr /R /C:"[routes]"
```

Comment: the grep in config list is nice idea :)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to differentiate routes per module so that we can use BjyAuthorize's ACL setup respectively in different situations.

While there is more than one way to do to this such as shown by [Jurian Sluiman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434223/jurian-sluiman) to read in all the routes (variables changed):

```php
<?php

// $this->services instanceof Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager

$config = $this->services->get('Config');
$routes = $config['router']['routes'];
```

You can obtain them as follows for future differentiation per module in a **function**:

```php
<?php

// $this->services instanceof Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager

/**
 * Load the Application's active modules.  
 * @note May need to specify additional modules that may not be 
 * loaded at this runtime.
 */
$moduleManager = $this->services->get('ModuleManager');
$moduleManager->loadModules();

// Retrieve array of module names.
$modules = $moduleManager->getModules();

// Setup a container for all active routes.
$routes = []; 

// Build array of all active routes.
foreach ($modules as $moduleName) {
    $module = $moduleManager->getModule($moduleName);
    $routes[$moduleName] = array_keys($module->getConfig()['router']['routes']);
}
// Whatever you care to do with them.
echo $routes;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of routes from the router using the following code snippet. `$mvcEvent` is an instance of `Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent` and `TreeRouteStack` is `Zend\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack`.

```php
$router = $mvcEvent->getRouter();
$routes = (array) $router->getRoutes();
$routes = array_values($routes);
$routes = count($routes) > 0 ? array_keys($routes[0]) : [];
```